# Reorderable intent configuration widget iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios14, widgetkit

I'm trying to learn the different possibilities of iOS widgets. So far I have successfully learned Static, Intent configuration widget.

I saw the iOS Clock widget where I can able to reorder the cities. I wonder how to do this. Any help would be very much appreciated.

I've added the Clock widget below for reference.

[image: Clock widget]

Comment: I checked the parameters section in the intent configuration and I don't see such possibility. But Clock widget comes from Apple. System apps can do much more (use private API etc.) than user-created apps. If you see this behaviour in *non-Apple* apps, then this is the proof that it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing all possible works in the `.intentdefinition` file, I got the answer.

We just need to enable two Checkboxes in the `.intentdefinition` file.

1. Enable "Supports multiple values" just below the `type` dropdown
2. Enable the "Fixed Size" checkbox and define how many entries you want to be based on the widget size

[image]

Comment: Important to not is that you have to use the option to dynamically provide the parameter options. That means static enums won’t work this way to have this reorder-able behavior.